# 2 GFCI's in master bathroom. Neither works

Tags: receptacle

In our master bedroom we have 2 separate vanities and each has it's own GFCI. That's how the house was when we bought it. At some point neither worked. So I replaced both and they still don't work and when I press "reset" neither will click in. The little light in the bottom right corner on both is red. I plugged in my tester and there is no power to either outlet. I checked the circuit breaker but it's fine. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Since the light is on you have power. Have the ever worked? Is one feeding the other? I have had a customer put in new GFCI’s that were on the same circuit as the old ones but the self test caused them not to be able to reset where they did with the older model. Another customer had 6 or 8 in a row each feeding the next from the load press test on the last one and most of them tripped. To get them to reset he had to do them in a specific order. Only one may be needed. If the hot and neutral are crossed they also won’t work.

Comment: You have to push pretty hard to reset on some.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of changing the one on the end of the line to a regular receptacle. I'll double check the wires. Thank you!

Comment: What make and model are your new GFCIs?

Comment: Is there anything on the load side of the GFCIs? Make sure you aren't powering the devices from the load side.